# MKStoreKit4.1 Buy Feature does nothing?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have an iphone application in which i am trying to implement subscription with mkstorekit 4.1.everything works fine except that this code. in success i was adding the subscribed view. but it is not getting called at all.Can anybody help me?

```
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:kFeatureAId onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature) 
     { 
                     //isPurchased = YES;
         NSLog(@"Purchased: in commmmpletion %@", purchasedFeature);
         [self showsubscribedview];

    } onCancelled:^ { 

        //purchas = YES; 
        NSLog(@" User Cancelled Transaction");
        return; 

    }];
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you following this article??
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/using-mkstorekit-in-your-apps/

I think you have not registered your purchase.

Comment: Ya i did .when i go to next tab and come back i am testing

Comment: if([[MKStoreManager sharedManager] isSubscriptionActive:kFeatureAId]) { //unlock i
 
        //NSLog(@"from appear %@",[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] isSubscriptionActive:kFeatureAId]);

        [self showsubscribedview]; 
   }
      
like this and it is ahowing the correct view at that time

Comment: But unfortunately when i am testing in the device it is not getting.when i came to that view it is showing the unsubscribed view every time.but when i am trying to purchase it is showing i have already subscribed to this

Comment: I want to say have you configured the products list in itunes connect??

Comment: yes for sure.the only doubt i have is i am not using the server part of that mkstorekit.because i dnt have a server.i am using the same code for checking is subscription active .is that the reason?

Comment: Why you are not using direct store kit api??